# reporting services physical path of the folder

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

I created a folder using the Report Manager URL but I would like to copy all the files to the different folder. Where is my folder located? I searched it but couldn't find it. Please let me know.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

They aren't stored as physical files. They are stored in the Reporting Services database (called ReportServer by default if you don't have a named instance.)

You can't directly copy the files, but you can move them with the Report Manager interface.

To copy the files, use the [RS scripting utility](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162839.aspx), or download and then upload the .rdl files to the new location.